# How to standardize address type properly

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to standardize street address by converting the abbreviations to the full word (e.g. RD - Road). I created many lines to account for different spellings and ran into an issue where one replace code overrode another one

```
import pandas as pd 

mydata = {'Street_type': ['PL', 'pl', 'Pl', 'PLACE', 'place']}
mydata = pd.DataFrame(mydata)

mydata['Street_type'] = mydata['Street_type'].replace('PL','Place',regex=True)
mydata['Street_type'] = mydata['Street_type'].replace('pl','Place',regex=True)
mydata['Street_type'] = mydata['Street_type'].replace('Pl','Place',regex=True)
mydata['Street_type'] = mydata['Street_type'].replace('PLACE','Place',regex=True)
mydata['Street_type'] = mydata['Street_type'].replace('place','Place',regex=True)
```

Instead of Place, I got Placeace. What is the best way to avoid this error? Do I write a if-else statement or any function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `string.replace()` doesn't have any keyword arguments. Have you tested your code? If so, what's your output (please add to the answer)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I edited my original post, hope that makes sense

Comment: @aydow this isn't string replace but [pandas' Series replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html)

Answer (score 2):

Among other problems, you have overlapping logic: you fail to check that the target ("old") string is a full word before you replace it.  For instance, with the input type of "PLACE", you trigger both the first and third replacements, generating `PlaceACE` and then `PlaceaceACE` before you get to the condition you wanted.

You need to work through your tracking and exclusion logic carefully, and then apply only *one* of the replacements.  You can check the length of the street_type and apply the unique transition you need for that length.

If you're trying to convert a `case` statement, then you need to follow that logic pattern, rather than the successive applications you coded.  You can easily look up how to simulate a "case" statement in Python.

Also consider using a translation dictionary, such as

```
type_trans = {
    "pl":    "Place",
    "Pl":    "Place",
    "PLACE": "Place",
    ...
}
```

Then your change is simply

```
mydata['Street_type'] = type_trans[mydata['Street_type']]
```

Also, you might list all of the variants in a tuple, such as:

```
type_place = ("PL", "Pl", "pl", "PLACE", "place")
if mydata['Street_type'] in type_place
mydata['Street_type'] = "Place"
```

... but be sure to generalize this properly for your entire list of street types.

Comment: so my dataset is huge and that I have thousands of street type variations. I'm used to sql statement where you write "case when 'pl' then 'place'", basically I'm trying to convert that logic in python

Comment: thanks. While I have trouble with mydata['Street_type'] = type_trans[mydata['Street_type']], I was able to use this instead:                                for abr, word in type_trans.items():
    mydata.Street_type = mydata.Street_type.replace(abr, word)

Comment: That is still prone to fail in the same way.  You need to check that the *entire* `Street_type` matches the abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this correctly with a single pass if you  use a proper regex here, e.g. use word boundaries (\b):

```
In [11]: places = ["PL", "pl", "Pl", "PLACE", "Place", "place"]

In [12]: mydata.Street_type
Out[12]:
0       PL
1       pl
2       Pl
3    PLACE
4    place
Name: Street_type, dtype: object

In [13]: mydata.Street_type.replace("(^|\b)({})(\b|$)".format("|".join(places)), "Place", regex=True)
Out[13]:
0    Place
1    Place
2    Place
3    Place
4    Place
Name: Street_type, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Needlemanwunch
def zeros(shape):
    retval = []
    for x in range(shape[0]):
        retval.append([])
        for y in range(shape[1]):
            retval[-1].append(0)
    return retval

match_award      = 10
mismatch_penalty = -3
gap_penalty      = -4 # both for opening and extanding

def match_score(alpha, beta):
    if alpha == beta:
        return match_award
    elif alpha == '-' or beta == '-':
        return gap_penalty
    else:
        return mismatch_penalty

def finalize(align1, align2):
    align1 = align1[::-1]    #reverse sequence 1
    align2 = align2[::-1]    #reverse sequence 2

    i,j = 0,0

    #calcuate identity, score and aligned sequeces
    symbol = ''
    found = 0
    score = 0
    identity = 0
    for i in range(0,len(align1)):
        # if two AAs are the same, then output the letter
        if align1[i] == align2[i]:                
            symbol = symbol + align1[i]
            identity = identity + 1
            score += match_score(align1[i], align2[i])

        # if they are not identical and none of them is gap
        elif align1[i] != align2[i] and align1[i] != '-' and align2[i] != '-': 
            score += match_score(align1[i], align2[i])
            symbol += ' '
            found = 0

        #if one of them is a gap, output a space
        elif align1[i] == '-' or align2[i] == '-':          
            symbol += ' '
            score += gap_penalty

    identity = float(identity) / len(align1) * 100

    print('Similarity =', "%3.3f" % identity, 'percent')
    print('Score =', score)
#     print(align1)
#     print(symbol)
#     print(align2)


def needle(seq1, seq2):
    m, n = len(seq1), len(seq2)  # length of two sequences

    # Generate DP table and traceback path pointer matrix
    score = zeros((m+1, n+1))      # the DP table

    # Calculate DP table
    for i in range(0, m + 1):
        score[i][0] = gap_penalty * i
    for j in range(0, n + 1):
        score[0][j] = gap_penalty * j
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            match = score[i - 1][j - 1] + match_score(seq1[i-1], seq2[j-1])
            delete = score[i - 1][j] + gap_penalty
            insert = score[i][j - 1] + gap_penalty
            score[i][j] = max(match, delete, insert)

    # Traceback and compute the alignment 
    align1, align2 = '', ''
    i,j = m,n # start from the bottom right cell
    while i > 0 and j > 0: # end toching the top or the left edge
        score_current = score[i][j]
        score_diagonal = score[i-1][j-1]
        score_up = score[i][j-1]
        score_left = score[i-1][j]

        if score_current == score_diagonal + match_score(seq1[i-1], seq2[j-1]):
            align1 += seq1[i-1]
            align2 += seq2[j-1]
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        elif score_current == score_left + gap_penalty:
            align1 += seq1[i-1]
            align2 += '-'
            i -= 1
        elif score_current == score_up + gap_penalty:
            align1 += '-'
            align2 += seq2[j-1]
            j -= 1

    # Finish tracing up to the top left cell
    while i > 0:
        align1 += seq1[i-1]
        align2 += '-'
        i -= 1
    while j > 0:
        align1 += '-'
        align2 += seq2[j-1]
        j -= 1

    finalize(align1, align2)

needle('kizlerlo','killerpo' )

***********************************************************************************************************************

#import textdistance as txd
import numpy
txd.overlap('kizlerlo','kilerpo' )
txd.jaro('kizlerlo','killerpo' )
txd.cosine('kizlerlo','killerpo' )
#txd.needleman_wunsch('kizlerlo','killerpo' )
txd.jaro_winkler('kizlerlo','killerpo' )
#txd.smith_waterman('Loans and Accounts','Loans Accounts' )
#txd.levenshtein.normalized_similarity('Loans and Accounts','Loans Accounts' )
from scipy.spatial import distance
a = 'kizlerlo'
b = 'kilerpoo'
#txd.gotoh('Loans and Accounts','Loans Accounts' )
print(txd.needleman_wunsch.normalized_similarity('Loans and Accounts','Loans Accounts' ))

***************************************************************************************************************************

#Euclidean
import math
import numpy as np
def euclid(str1,str2):
    dist=0.0
    x=str1
    y=str2
    set1=set()
    for a in range(0,len(x)):
        set1.add(x[a])
    for a in range(0,len(y)):
        set1.add(y[a])
    vec1=[None]*len(set1)
    vec2=[None]*len(set1)
    for counter,each_char in enumerate(set1):
        vec1[counter]=x.count(each_char)
        vec2[counter]=y.count(each_char)
    dist=1/(1+math.sqrt(sum([(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(vec1, vec2)])))
    print(dist)
euclid('kizlerlo','killerpo')

***************************************************************************************************************************


from similarity.qgram import QGram
import affinegap
qgram = QGram(2)
#print(qgram.distance('kizlerlo', 'killerpo'))
affinegap.affineGapDistance('kizlerlokill' ,'erpozlerlzler')

***************************************************************************************************************************

#manhattan
def manhattan(str1,str2):
    dist=0.0
    x=str1
    y=str2
    set1=set()
    for a in range(0,len(x)):
        set1.add(x[a])
    for a in range(0,len(y)):
        set1.add(y[a])
    vec1=[None]*len(set1)
    vec2=[None]*len(set1)
    for counter,each_char in enumerate(set1):
        vec1[counter]=x.count(each_char)
        vec2[counter]=y.count(each_char)
    #dist= sum([np.abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(vec1, vec2)])
    dist=1/(1+sum([np.abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(vec1, vec2)]))
    print(dist)
manhattan('kizlerlo','killerpo')

import jellyfish
import json
from Levenshtein import distance,jaro_winkler,jaro,ratio,seqratio

def comp(a,b):
    return jellyfish.jaro_winkler(a,b)*100 + distance(a,b) + jaro(a,b)*100
ip = {"CED":"WALMART INC_10958553"}

ala = {}
for index,row in df_ala.iterrows():
    a = ip.get("CED")
    b = row['NN_UID']
    c = comp(a,b)
    ala.update({row['N_UID'] : c})

ala_max = max(ala, key=ala.get)

ala_f = {"ALACRA" : ala_max}
ces_f = {"CESIUM" : "WALMART_10958553_CESIUM"}
dun_f = {"DUNS" : "WALMART_10958053_DUNS"}
ref_f = {"REF" : "WALMART INC_10958553_REF"}
cax_f = {"CAX" : "WALMART LTD_10958553_CAX"}
final_op = {**ala_f,**ces_f,**dun_f,**ref_f,**cax_f }
final_json = json.dumps(final_op)
print(final_json)

from flask import Flask,request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return jsonify({"response":"Get request called"})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        req_Json = request.json
        name = req_Json['name']
        return jsonify({"response": "Hi" + name})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True,port = 9090)

{
    "name": "Mike"
}

import usaddress
import pandas as pd
import statistics 

#sa = dict(usaddress.parse('123 Main St. Suite  Chicago, IL' ))
adr = pd.read_excel('C:\\VINAYAK\\Address.xlsx')
adr.columns = ['Address']

strlen = []
scr = []
loop = adr['Address'].tolist()
for i in loop:
    strlen.append(len(i))
x = statistics.median(strlen)
for i in loop:
    sa = dict(usaddress.parse(i))
    sa = list(sa.values())
    a = 0
    if len(i) > x :
        a+= 5
    if 'AddressNumber' in sa :  
        a+= 23
    if 'StreetName' in sa :  
        #a = a + 20
        a+= 17
    if 'OccupancyType' in sa :  
        a+= 6
    if 'OccupancyIdentifier' in sa :  
        a+= 12
    if 'PlaceName' in sa :  
        a+= 12
    if 'StateName' in sa :  
        a+= 13
    if 'ZipCode' in sa :  
        a+= 12
    scr.append(a)
adr['Adr_Score'] = scr
adr.head()
#(pd.DataFrame([(key) for  key in sa.items()])).transpose()
#pd.DataFrame(dict([(value, key) for key, value in sa.items()])) 
#pd.DataFrame(dict([(value, key) for key, value in sa.items()]))
# df_ts = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['AddressNumber' , 'Age', 'City' , 'Country'])
# df_ts.append(sa, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=None)
# df_ts.head()
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile
# core = []
# f = open('C:/Users/s.natarajakarayalar/1.txt','r')
# core.append(str(f.readlines()))
# print(core)
import os
import zipfile
import re
import nltk

import os
core = []
with zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Users/s.natarajakarayalar/TF.zip') as z:
    a = 0
    for filename in z.namelist():
        #if a < 1:
        #if not os.path.isdir(filename):
            # read the file
        with z.open(filename) as f:
                #a = 2
            x = f.readlines()
            core = core + x

with open('C:/Users/s.natarajakarayalar/fins.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in core:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
# for i in core:
#     if k < 5:
#         tkt = re.sub(r'.*CONTENT', '', i)
#         new_core.append(tkt)
#         k = k+1

# for item in core:
#     new_core.append(len(item.split()))
# print(sum(new_core))
# from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
# new_core = []
# stp = ['URL:https://','TITLE:b','META-KEYWORDS:','None','DOC ID:','CONTENT:b','URL:','TITLE:','META-CONTENT:']
# #new_core = [word for word in core if word not in stopwords]
# for i in core:
#     wk = word_tokenize(i)
#     for w in wk:
#         if w not in stp:
#             new_core.append(w)
```